# Visual Studio 2010: How to add a simple file not as a resource?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just want to have a "data" directory in the project, and that it will be located at the startup directory of the application. When I add files with drag&drop they're not appearing in the startup directory of the application (they're embedded or something).

Seems to be very simple but not found any solution yet =[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have added the files right click on each and select "properties".

Set the following properties:

- "Build Action" to "Content"
- "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer"

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy file in it. This will force directory creation in the output path